# Inheriting Managed Objects

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

This is a bit tricky problem and i am new to core data. I have a xcdatamodel containing few Entites inside my swift frame-work. 
When an application uses my frame work it uses the entities in my data model through a class called CoreDataManager.
Two questions here: 
1. Can the application have its own data model file with another set of entites and use it with frame work data model. (I think this is possible with two managed object context, better approach would be helpful)
2. How can the applications entites have a relation with the entites in the frame work. Any core data experts please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

An app using the framework can also have its own data model and persistent store. That could be a completely separate Core Data stack. It could also combine the framework data model with their own to form a single unified model. If they're using `NSPersistentContainer`, they'd do this by having more than one `NSPersistentStoreDescription` in the `persistentStoreDescriptions` array-- one for their model, and one for the framework. The container would then use a unified model containing entities from both.

If they're not using `NSPersistentContainer`, then `NSManagedObjectModel` has methods for merging multiple data models into a single model object.

If you go with two separate Core Data stacks, there can't be any relationships between their objects and framework objects, because they'll be in separate data stores. If you use the unified approach, then relationships just work because it's a single data model and a single persistent store.